# AngularJS modify td based on other td

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a <tr> which is controlled via a ng-repeat to pass in an object.  One of the <td> elements is a textfield, and I have a function on $scope that returns the # of lines of text.  Now, on an another <td> in that same row, I want to add as many select boxes as I have lines in the textfield, so I tried something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="variable in variables">
    <td>
      <label for="varValues">Choices:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="variable.extras" id="varValues" cols="40" rows="5">{{variable.extras}}</textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr element-repeat="numberOfRowsForChoiceVariable(variable)">
          <select class="form-control" ng-options="">
            <option value="">-- Default Skill --</option>
          </select>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
```

I'm getting just a single <select> element in that second column.  How do I make that get re-evaluated when I change the contents of that text field?

Comment: And what does `numberOfRowsForChoiceVariable()` look like?

Comment: it returns the number select boxes that I want to exist based on the number of lines in the variable.extras model

Comment: That tr should really be an ng-repeat that just loops the right number of times.  But the issue still exists of how do I rewrite that td element whenever the variable.extras changes?

Comment: Might need to create a fiddle so we can see what's going on. Here's a start. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ryu6tnjq/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sgrosch1/jwkyk8qs/2/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to turn your quantity value into an array. Something like this should do:

```
$scope.getNumArray = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

You'd use this inside `numberOfRowsForChoiceVariable(variable)` to return the array rather than an integer.

Comment: I changed it from element-repeat="" to be an `ng-repeat="x in numberOfRowsForChoiceVariable(variable) track by $index"` and it returns the array like you showed.  I'm still just getting a single select element though on my page.